# C Language - [copy in place] float* to char* and the reverse

Tags: c, pointers, programming-languages, type-conversion

I want to copy a float buffer into a char (byte) buffer without allocating memory for two separate buffers.  In another words I want to use one buffer and copy in place.
The Problem is that if I need a float buffer then in order to copy that to a char then I will need a char* pointer;  If I were copying from float* to float* it would be easy as I would just pass in the same pointer for the target and the source.

eg.

```
void CopyInPlace(float* tar, float* src, int len) {
....
}
CopyInPlace(someBuffer, someBuffer, 2048);

void PackFloatToChar(char* tar, float* src, int len) {

}
????????
```

How would I do this?

Does memcpy copy in place?, if passed in the same pointer?

Comment: what do you hope to achieve by copying in place?

Comment: What format do you want the floats converted to chars be ? What if the space for the char* needs more space than you have in your float* ? Or is casting the float* to a char* all you need ?

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense. What is "copy in place" supposed to mean? If you have only *one* buffer, then you can't *copy* anything anywhere.

Comment: `memcpy` does not allow this, but `memmove` allows source and destination that overlap, so you can copy bytes onto themselves to your heart's content (this comment is tongue-in-cheek. Get your programming advice from the answers instead)

Comment: You can overwrite your input buffer and then reuse it as your output.
You do this when you need to save memory like on embedded devices.  I only have 1mb of ram to work with.  

void CopyInPlaceMult4(int* tar, int* src, int len) {
    int* val = src;
    int* end = src + len-1;
    for( ; val<end; tar++,val++) {
        *tar = (*val)*4;
    }
}

//copying in place only uses 16 bytes (4 ints)
    int buf[3];
    buf[0] = 2;
    buf[1] = 4;
    buf[2] = 8;
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2]);
    CopyInPlaceMult4(buf, buf, 3);
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2]);

Comment: @juxstapose 1/ The condition in your for loop is wrong. 2/ We did not say that doing an operation (here, multiplying by 4) in place was wrong. We said that "copying in place", the kind of operation that you would conceptually achieve by passing `memmove` the same pointers for source and destination, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems a bit confused.

Do you want to simply interpret an array of floats as a char array (for something like writing to a file?). If so, simply cast. All pointers in C can be represented by char*'s.

memcpy will copy from one memory location to another. But keep careful track of whether your "len" parameter is the number of floats or number of bytes. If "len" is the count of floats in the array, multiply it by sizeof(float) in the memcpy call.

Comment: ah ok memcpy works.  However, what is the algorithm for unpacking the bytes to floats?  I will post this as my next question.  Thanks!

Comment: @juxstapose You cannot use memcpy to copy to the same buffer. You need memmove of the source/destination overlap.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a `float` pointer to a `char` pointer, a cast is sufficient.

```
float* someBuffer;
...
char* someBuffer2 = (char*)someBuffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the casting that's already been recommended, you might want to consider using a union, something like:

```
union x { 
    float float_val;
    char bytes[sizeof(float)];
};
```

There isn't likely to be a huge difference either way, but you may find one more convenient or readable than the other.

Comment: The big difference with gcc is that this solution circumvents the strict aliasing rule. With another compiler it is not guaranteed, because accessing an union through another field than it was last written to is just as undefined as casting pointers and then accessing them in the standard.